# findViewById return null in custom view

Tags: java, android

I tried clean the project and using inflate,however it didn't work.
But maybe I didn't use the inflate right.
I need some help for using the inflate right or any ideas to make the pointer right.

here is the code

**MainActivity.java -> activity_main.xml -> FaceGridView.java**

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
FaceGridView myGridview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myGridview = (FaceGridView) findViewById( R.id.facegridview);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.example.ngvvp.FaceGridView
    android:id="@+id/facegridview" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   >
   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainRLayout" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    >
         <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
              android:id="@+id/pager" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="285px"
              android:layout_above="@+id/pagerIndicator"
               /> 

  <com.example.ngvvp.CirclePageIndicator
       android:id="@+id/pagerIndicator" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="15px" 
       android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" 
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
       android:padding="3dp" 
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

**FaceGridView.java**

```
public class FaceGridView extends ViewGroup {
public PageIndicator mIndicator;
private ViewPager awesomePager;
private PagerAdapter pm;
private RelativeLayout mainRLayout;
public Context myContext;
public View MAIN ;

public void initial() {
    MAIN = (View)findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
    mIndicator = (PageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.pagerIndicator);
    awesomePager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mainRLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainRLayout);
    System.out.println("MAIN["+MAIN+"] \n"+
                       "mIndicator["+mIndicator+"] \n"+
                       "awesomePager["+awesomePager+"] \n"+
                       "mainRLayout["+mainRLayout+"] \n"+
                       "myContext["+myContext+"]\n" );
}
 public FaceGridView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.myContext = context;
    initial();
    InsideMethod();
}

public FaceGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.myContext = context;
    initial();
    InsideMethod();
}
```

except myContext other pointers are all null

```
09-04 14:52:46.644: I/System.out(23503): MAIN[null] 
09-04 14:52:46.644: I/System.out(23503): mIndicator[null] 
09-04 14:52:46.644: I/System.out(23503): awesomePager[null] 
09-04 14:52:46.644: I/System.out(23503): mainRLayout[null] 
09-04 14:52:46.644: I/System.out(23503): myContext[com.example.ngvvp.MainActivity@41ea2858]
```

I have no idea what happened.
Anyone have any idea?

Comment: i think because there is no active view in your initial method. meaning  android doesnt know where to find those id. View main = anotherView.findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: where do you call initial()? if in the constructor then its a wrong place,  try in onFinishInflate()

Comment: Please post your `FaceGridView` constructors.

Comment: sorry i missed it ,now it's Edited

Comment: see my comment above

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);

 mIndicator = (PageIndicator) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
awesomePager = (ViewPager) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

Comment: thank you,and just make sure 
Is row a View? 
and What shout i type at parent?whose parent is that?

Comment: @楊晉豪 try calling initial() in onFinishInflate()

Comment: after i tried its still null,but still thank you too

Comment: what is null? Log.d number of child views and iterate over them logging their ids

Comment: i used your way to call the parent view then parent.findViewbyId 
and use Log to print the pointer content,find both the pointers are null,
so i think i have other mistakes at other place.

Answer (score 0):

There is the result that my classmate tried can make the pointers right.
Its not the way i want ,but the result is.it works.Post it for people who encounter the same problem to me.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
FaceGridView myGridview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        myGridview = (FaceGridView) findViewById( R.id.facegridview);
        myGridview.initial(this);
    }

}
```

**FaceGridView.java**

```
public class FaceGridView extends ViewGroup {
public PageIndicator mIndicator;
private ViewPager awesomePager;
private PagerAdapter pm;
private RelativeLayout mainRLayout;
public Context myContext;
public View MAIN ;
ArrayList<Category> codeCategory;

public void initial(Context ctx) {

    this.myContext = ctx;


    mIndicator = (PageIndicator)   ((Activity) myContext).findViewById(R.id.pagerIndicator); 
    awesomePager = (ViewPager)   ((Activity) myContext).findViewById(R.id.pager); 

    System.out.println( "myContext["+myContext+"] \n"+
                        "mIndicator["+mIndicator+"] \n"+
                        "awesomePager["+awesomePager+"] \n" );

    InsideMethod();
}

public FaceGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    System.out.println( "FaceGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) ["+context+"] ");
//  this.myContext = context;
//        initial();
//        InsideMethod();
}
```

Its my first time ask question on **stackoverflow**,i never thought get so many replies in such short time, you guys make me feel love **TAT**,thank you all.

Comment: haha ok i'll use Log instead of my bad habit system.out.print. thank you~